# Delete Columns Based on information

Tags: excel, vba

I am attempting to delete columns based on information that is not there.

I want to check all of row 4 and if each cell is not equal to the following criteria i want to delete the column.

**Criteria**
Empty cell 
ID
Total
147
Area

I can't seem to figure out where i am going wrong - it seems if i run my code like 10 times it finally manages to complete my task - but it should work in one attempt

```
For Each cel_1 In Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("4:4")
    If cel_1.Value <> "" And cel_1.Value <> "ID" And cel_1.Value <> "Total" _
        And cel_1.Value <> "147" And cel_1.Value <> "Area" Then
        cel_1.EntireColumn.Delete  
    End If
Next
```

Comment: You should implement a breakaway from the `For` loop. When your criteria are met and after the row is deleted, the code continues- but now on what was previously row 5.

Comment: AH! of course, so when it deletes a column it then skips the next column and continues it's search! okay perfect i shall look into how to resolve this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try another kind of loop

```
Sub DeleteColumns()
    For i = 1 To ActiveSheet.Cells(4, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
        If ActiveSheet.Cells(4, i) <> "" And ActiveSheet.Cells(4, i) <> "ID" And ActiveSheet.Cells(4, i) <> "Total" _
        And ActiveSheet.Cells(4, i) <> "147" And ActiveSheet.Cells(4, i) <> "Area" Then
            ActiveSheet.Columns(i).Delete
            i = i - 1
        End If
    Next i


End Sub
```